# on mouse over content of memory variable will be displayed in label

Tags: c#, memory, calculator

First of all guys i am new here and looking forward to posting the questions i have and to answering the one that the others.

So i am trying to create a simple calculator application i have everything working when it comes to calculation, but i am stuck at memory part of the calc (specially mouse overs). so my task is to create 2 new components one is a button and other is label, i have already coded the part where the content of "Answer TextBox" will be copied to the memory variable. The part where i am stuck is when the user moves the mouse over the label, the value in the memory variable will appear in this label, and then disappear, when the mouse moves away from the label.

code that i have so far,

EDIT : I fixed iT.....

Answer (score 0):

What about using label1_MouseEnter and label1_MouseLeave?

```
private void label1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = Value.ToString();
}

private void label1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "";
}
```

Is this what you want?
Do you know where to find Events in the properties section?

Comment: if you look at my code i already have it and it doesn't work, it will be memLbl_mousehover event right in the middle

Comment: Ok, sorry. Then i dont know what would be the problem.

Comment: the problem is that when i run my program with the code posted above and when i click on memory button and hover over to the label in my output window i get error  ...................... A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ParseSingle(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.Single.Parse(String s)
   at Calculator.calcForm.memLbl_MouseHover(Object sender, EventArgs  in c:\Users\Documents\C#\Calculator\Calculator\Form1.cs:line 134

Comment: I FIXED IT i just declared memory variable globally and took one line of code out, thanks for your help MasterXD